# How to initialize subsonic programmatically at runtime

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

Would like to initialize @ run-time as needed with the connection string coming from a non app.config source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Subsonic 3 I think that the answer is all ready on subsonic site

http://subsonicproject.com/docs/3.0_Multiple_Databases

Also if you look the creation of the template, you see where the connection string is called.

For the subsonic 2, there is a similar way, the connection string can used in most of cases to ask for data.